# Jquery append html button not following css

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

here is a simple version of my code

```
var x='<button class="btn btn-primary" id="cite">Add to cite</button>';
jQuery("button").click(function() {
     jQuery(".output").append(x);
}
```

the button appended to the html is a very basic html button, but other class follow the bootstrap css.

How do i get the button to follow my css?

here are my complete code,

```
<script>
jQuery("button").click(function() {
                var inpu = jQuery(userInput).val().replace(/ /g, '+');
                var card1 = '<div class="card card-block"><p class="card- text">Title:'
                var card2 = '<br>author：'
                var card3 = '<br>Publisher:'
                var card4 = '<br><button class="btn btn-primary" id="cite">Add</button></p></div>'


                jQuery.get("http://api.crossref.org/works?query=" + inpu + "&rows=5", function(data) {
                    //                  var x = JSON.stringify(data.message.items[0]);
                    for(count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
                        jQuery(".output").append(card1 + JSON.stringify(data.message.items[count].title + card2 + card3 + data.message.items[count].publisher + card4 ));
                    }

                });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: is this inside document . ready?

Comment: so it's actually outputting the button?

Comment: Can you show us the minimum code that doesn't work? Like how are you applying this script, how are you including the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use addClass for button like this.

```js
var x = '<button class="btn btn-primary" id="cite">Add to cite</button>';
$(document).on('click', '#btnAppend', function() {
  $(".output").append(x);
  $('#cite').addClass('bootstrapclass');

});
```

```css
.bootstrapclass {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='output' </div>
 <input type='button' value='Append' id='btnAppend' />
```